# Page CSS is not changed, what is not working?

Tags: firefox, testing, firefox-addon

I am building a firefox addon through the Mozilla Addon Builder https://builder.addons.mozilla.org

I'm starting really basic, I figure it doesn't get any more simple than changing google.com to red. I made the css change the body, html, and divs and added important, so I could be sure that if the stylesheet displays, it will change the background red, and will overwrite the current css.

However, when I activate it (through the testing button which installs the addon), nothing happens. The CSS is not injected into the page.

Here is what the extension looks like:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Here is the code:

**main.js**

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

 pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.google.com/*",
  contentStyleFile: data.url("data/style.css")
 });
```

**style.css**

```
html, body, div {
    background: red !important;
}
```

I also tried using the following urls, all which did not work either:

- http://google.com/*
- https://google.com/*
- http://www.google.com/*
- https://www.google.com/*
- http://google.com/
- https://google.com/
- http://www.google.com/
- https://www.google.com/

I also tried changing the following locations to style.css, which did not make any difference either:

- style.css
- data/style.css
- ../data/style.css

I also tried removing the sdk/ from the data and pagemod variables, but that did not work either.

Why is it not working and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

[Match patterns](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod/match-pattern.html#Wildcards) contain only one `*`.

The pattern `"*.google.com"` matches all the Google url's in your list.  Match pattern can also be a regular expression.  You can match `http://google.ie` and all the other `google.*`'s with

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: /.*\/(\/\w*\.)?google\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}\/.*/,
  contentStyleFile: data.url("style.css")
});
```

Comment: well that doesn't really matter because just http://google.com without any wildcards still does nothing.

Comment: No wildcard in the match pattern matches only that URL which is spelled exactly the same as the pattern, from the first to the last character.

Two wildcards is non-valid and results in no matches, as shown in the code you originally posted.

The happy medium between 0 and 2 is 1.  One wildcard - `*.example.com` matches all of

`http://example.com/`
`http://foo.example.com/`
`https://example.com/`
`http://example.com/foo`
`ftp://foo.example.com/`

A copy of your add-on with only one wildcard (everything else the same) is at https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/184965/latest/

Comment: no, as i said, i tried something different than the code above. Anyways this does not work. Changing the pattern is not the reason it is not working. Perhaps come up with different solution?